# SignalR Service Output Binding not working in Isolated Process?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I've created an Azure Function that's based on a `ServiceBusTrigger`. What I would like to do, is consume the trigger and generate a SignalR message for my Blazor Server app. So I've created the following code (loosely based on this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/Extensions/SignalR/SignalRFunction.cs)):

```cs
    public static class InspectionPackageImport
    {
        [Function("SignalRFunction")]
        [SignalROutput(HubName = "import")]
        public static MyMessage Run([ServiceBusTrigger("import-request")] string json,
            [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = "import")] MyConnectionInfo connectionInfo,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("SignalRFunction");

            logger.LogInformation(json);
            logger.LogInformation($"Connection URL = {connectionInfo.Url}");

            var message = $"Output message created at {DateTime.Now}";

            return new MyMessage()
            {
                Target = "Broadcast",
                Arguments = new[] { message }
            };
        }

        public class MyConnectionInfo
        {
            public string Url { get; set; }

            public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyMessage
        {
            public string Target { get; set; }

            public object[] Arguments { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The trigger fires as expected and the function completes successfully. However, it appears that no message is sent. I'm currently using the Live Trace Tool in the Azure Portal (*SignalR->Diagnostic Settings->Open Live Trace Tool* - I have Connectivity and Messaging both selected). I've clicked Capture and I see no activity.

I'm running my Azure Functions locally using `func start`. Here's some sample output:

```
[2021-05-24T05:09:39.149Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2021-05-24T05:09:43.686Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000076775097'.
[2021-05-24T05:09:45.034Z] Executing 'Functions.RequestImport' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=2fe2d9d1-15dc-425b-852f-31e8227586af)
[2021-05-24T05:09:45.131Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2021-05-24T05:09:45.780Z] Executed 'Functions.RequestImport' (Succeeded, Id=2fe2d9d1-15dc-425b-852f-31e8227586af, Duration=773ms)
[2021-05-24T05:09:45.793Z] Executing 'Functions.SignalRFunction' (Reason='(null)', Id=94c0182d-dc5e-426e-8b91-c21bf62793d6)
[2021-05-24T05:09:45.796Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: c2bbaac3f15447c6b5b43598627f5012, SequenceNumber: 72, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2021-05-24T05:09:45.7390000Z, LockedUntilUtc: 2021-05-24T05:10:15.7390000Z, SessionId: (null)
[2021-05-24T05:09:46.157Z] {
[2021-05-24T05:09:46.160Z]   "Id": "64df027d-92ff-424f-9a04-bd2bf7dbbdda",
[2021-05-24T05:09:46.162Z]   "Name": "Level 2: 'First Graduate - FG0186'"
[2021-05-24T05:09:46.163Z] }
[2021-05-24T05:09:46.166Z] Connection URL = https://xxxx.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=import
[2021-05-24T05:09:46.517Z] Executed 'Functions.SignalRFunction' (Succeeded, Id=94c0182d-dc5e-426e-8b91-c21bf62793d6, Duration=736ms)
```

To begin with, I utilised the SignalR instance that my Blazor Server is based on. I currently have a second SignalR service set to "Serverless" mode, just in case that matters. The only thing I haven't configured is the Upstream URL Pattern. Which I'm trying to avoid - because I'm more interested in the `ServiceBusTrigger` than a `SignalRTrigger`.

I seem to be missing something? For example, do I need a "negotiate" function? The documentation isn't too clear at the moment.

**A little more testing**

I've just created test Function App that isn't .net 5/in an isolated process. With a copy of the [broadcast sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=csharp#broadcast-to-all-clients) code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;

namespace FunctionTest
{
    public static class Function3
    {
        [FunctionName("SendMessage")]
        public static Task SendMessage(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] object message,
            [SignalR(HubName = "import")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages)
        {
            return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    Target = "newMessage",
                    Arguments = new[] { message }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

After making the call via Postman, I get the same result. The function executes successfully, but no messages show up in the Live Trace Tool and there is no indication that the message failed. I don't think this is to do with the newer version of Azure Functions, it's just me! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The thing I was missing is that I needed to treat the Function App as a SignalR hub. I adjusted my Blazor app to make the following connection:

```cs
// The url to my local/debug Azure Functions instance:
_hubUrl = "http://localhost:7071/api";

_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(_hubUrl)
    .Build();

_hubConnection.On<string, string>("newMessage", BroadcastMessage);

await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
```

**Then** I started receiving messages from the Azure Function.

Which means that my Blazor app is now dealing with two SignalR services. One for the Blazor Server (in "Default" mode) and another for the Azure Function (in "Serverless" mode).

I'd like to know if there is a way to share the SignalR service that's running in "Default" mode. But that's a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67682008/share-signalr-service-with-blazor-server-and-azure-function)

Comment: I have the same problem that you faced above what do you mean by "treat the Function App as a SignalR hub", do you have any code example? Because I have exactly same problem when I run my function there is also no connection o Azure SignalR Serverless Service

Comment: It's been a while, but basically if you point a SignalR client to a URL, there needs to be a `/negotiate` route. The Function bindings fulfill that purpose. Which means you might be in a situation where you're waiting for your Azure Function to cold boot before the SignalR hub connects. In my case, I wanted to avoid this. Hopefully that makes sense...